# Dynamically loaded Markers: DDOS prevention

Tags: performance, google-maps, gis, scalability

My app shows a map where locations (or Markers) are dynamically loaded via an ajax (and database) request after every map Bounds changes.

I'm convinced that this solution is not scalable : at the moment, Europe area shows a total of 10 markers.
If the database grows and I display for instance 1000 locations, that means 1000 rows would be returned to the user.

*This is not a JS / UI since I use the MarkerCluster plugin and I avoid the redraw of loaded locations's markers.*

I made some tweaks :
- Delay the Ajax request thanks to an Idle gmaps event
- Increase the minimal zoom level, so the entire world can't be displayed.

But this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to approach this but I will just put here the two I think are most appropriate from your question.

First is to really control from your web app what information is asked for and when. You could write this all yourself in javascript and implement caching techniques ect. There are a number of libraries out there that do most of this work for you though.
I would recommend one of the following:

- [OpenGeo SDK](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/apps/clientsdkintro/index.html)
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
- [GeoExt](http://www.geoext.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)

All of these have ways of controlling local caching, when to get the data and what data is gathered from the server. Most of them can also be extended to add any functionality that is missing. The top two I know support google maps (as well as a number of others) as well.

If you need to add even more control over your data locally you could even look at implementing something like [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/). I think this is more suited to mobile applications or instances where the network connection is either really slow or intermittent.

This sort of solution should be able to easily handle 1000's to 10000's of features with 100's of users.

If you are really going to scale up to 100000's to 1000000's of features with 100's to 1000's of users then I would suggest adding a tile server to the soloution above. The tile server will sit between your web application and your data base. Most of them have lots of caching settings and optimistions for dealing with large datasets and pushing them out to a client. Because they push out tiles rather than features the data output remains reasonably constant even as the number of features grow. The OpenGeo SDK and Openlayers libraries I mentioned above can work really well with any of the following tile servers:

- [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)
- [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/)
- [MapGuide](https://mapguide.osgeo.org/)
- [Quantum GIS Server](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html)

If you are reluctant to do any coding there are some offers that work out of the box for enterprise environments. They are all expensive and from your question I think they are probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: You are right, I should consider server side solutions giving the scaling matters.